# Trying to match * / * regex

Tags: regex, xsd

I am trying to match a number of different things from an xml file using regex in an xsd file.

I am trying to exact match 0 or * / * and match 0-9 / 0-9 
The 0-9 are any digits 0 - 9 example 0 / 4 should match but 0 / a should show a non match / invalid entry.

List of possible entries.

```
0
0 / 0
1 / 4
22 / 22
* / *
```

examples of non allowed entries

```
1 ( no digits other than 0)
1 / a
a
```

Here is the regex that i am using but it has a flaw. It matches 0 fine but it still accepts 0 / a and it does not match * / * at all.

```
    ^.*\b(0|[0-9]\s\/\s[0-9]|\*\s\/\s\*)\b.*$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what's allowing `0 / a` is the `.*` that you are using, where the first `.*` matches nothing, `0` will match `0` and the last `.*` will match `/ a`. And I don't think you really need the word boundaries here.

Start by matching only `0`:

```
^0$
```

Then branch to accept `0-9 / 0-9`:

```
^(?:0|[0-9] / [0-9])$
```

And if you want to accept multiple digits, add in quantifiers. If you don't want to get stuff like `09 / 09`, then use `[1-9][0-9]*` instead:

```
^(?:0|[1-9][0-9]* / [1-9][0-9]*)$
```

To accept `0 / 0`, just add it with another 'or':

```
^(?:0|(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*) / (?:0|[1-9][0-9]*))$
```

And finally, to accept `*`, you can put it together with the `0` in a character class:

```
^(?:0|(?:[0*]|[1-9][0-9]*) / (?:[0*]|[1-9][0-9]*))$
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/gM3aU0)

Comment: That worked perfect and thanks for the link. I just started to learn regex. Thanks for the great explanation as well.

Comment: XSD regular expressions always match the entire value (or don't match at all), so ^ and $ aren't used for anchors in XSD regexes, and there is no concept of eager or greedy matching.  The XSD formulation of the solution would be something like `(0)|(([0*]|[1-9][0-9]*) / ([0*]|[1-9][0-9]*))`.  (If the expressions given really do work for the OP, then the OP may have been wrong to think an XSD schema was involved.)

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
([\d*]+\s\/\s[\d*]+|0)
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/fI0cS5

Comment: That does match but it also allows many preceding 0s. The above by Jerry does not. Thanks for trying though.